Cases inside a corollary
I do not like that the cases (items 1 and 2) are not no the same vertical axis. I would like to move the 1 to the axis where 2 is on.
\begin{corollary}[Измеримость и мера декартово произведения множеств]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Пусть $\left.A \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^p\right), \quad B \in \mathcal{(} \mathbb{R}^q\right)$ . Тогда $A \times B \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^{p+q}\right)$.
                  
        \item При  $A \times B \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^{p+q}\right)$.
              
              при этом при $0 \cdot+\infty=0$ ( и наоборот ) по свойству меры.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{corollary}



Add \mbox{} after the optional argument.

@egreg Actually, the amsthm documentation recommends \leavevmode instead of \mbox{}.

@Gargantuar No difference, in this case, apart that \mbox is described in the LaTeX manual and \leavemode isn't.

Add \mbox{} before enumerate.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Короллар}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}[Измеримость и мера декартово произведения множеств]\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Пусть $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^p)$, $B \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^q)$.
        Тогда $A \times B \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{p+q})$.

  \item При  $A \times B \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{p+q})$.
        при этом при $0 \cdot+\infty=0$ (и наоборот) по свойству меры.
\end{enumerate}
\end{corollary}

\end{document}

I removed all \left and \right commands that are completely unnecessary here (and add unwanted spaces). In the first item the comma is not part of the formula, so I split it into two.

Of course I'd define
\newcommand{\cL}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}

so the input is easier and more readable.
